# Hey, I'm trying to create a Application Window using GUI designer plugin in eclipse but it show me the following error

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, gui-builder

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
EventQueue cannot be resolved   hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 13 Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 7  Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 17 Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 36 Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 36 Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 37 Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a type hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 38 Java Problem
JFrame cannot be resolved to a variable hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 38 Java Problem

Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module 'Namaste'  hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 1  Java Problem
The package java.awt is not accessible  hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 1  Java Problem
The type javax.swing.JFrame is not accessible   hello.java  /Namaste/src    line 3  Java Problem
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) I'd recommend not using the GUI builder until you understand how to layout a GUI using the Java code (that you write). To use them well, it is necessary to understand how the layouts work in any case.

Comment: You need to configure the build path for your Java project. You probably also need to create a `module-info.java` file that contains the following line: `requires java.desktop;`

Comment: *"Thank you"* Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.